# failing to display the display window due to the pygame.display.update()

Tags: python, pygame

import pygame

from pygame.locals import*

from sys import exit

pygame.init()

SCREEN_size(1000,560)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_size,0,32)

font=pygame.font.SysFont("algerian",18)

font_height = font.get_lineSize()

eventtext=[]

pygame.display.update()

while True:

```
    event= pygame.event.wait()




    event.text.append(str(event))




    eventtext=eventtext[-SCREEN_size[1]/font_height:]




    if event.type==QUIT:




       exit()




    y=SCREEN_size[1]-font_height




    for text in reversed(eventtext):




            screen.blit(font.render(text,True,(0,0,0),(0,y))
```

pygame.display.update()

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.display.update()` should be inside your loop not before or after it.